# What are the files to upload to Web Server for a ASP.NET C# Project

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have designed one project asp C# in vs 2012, now I would like to host this project to server but I don't know which file should I Upload? I signed up for free web hosting that I just sign up to test my website. but I didn't upload any file of my project yet because I don't know that Should I upload all file of my project or I need to modify something. please help me

Comment: Right click on the project name and press "Publish..." on the context menu, this will generate the list of files you need to copy over to the server.

Comment: @just.another.programmer +1 for removing the spam.

Answer (score 0):

This is discussed in detail [here](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/deployment/deploying-web-site-projects/determining-what-files-need-to-be-deployed-cs).  In short, it depends if you made a Web Site Project or a Web Application project.

**For a Web Site**

Upload all of the `.aspx`, `.aspx.cs`, and `.aspx.cs.designer` files as well as anything in the `App_Code` folder.  You'll also need any static content files (like images, scripts, styles).

**For a Web Application**

Upload all the markup files (like `.aspx`).  You do not need to upload `.cs` files.  Instead, upload the compiled assemblies from your bin folder.

Comment: It would be better to tell the OP how to use Publish

Comment: don't use website projects...IMO